# How to select random data from database with no repeat

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Currently, I'm working on the Lucky Draw system.

The process of the system is when a user clicks on the draw button it selects a random id from database where `attendance="Present"`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;




public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lucky"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE 'Attendance' = 'Present' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["EMP_ID"].ToString();

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It not working with the LIMIT function.I'm using Local DB @Brien

Comment: Since you're using SqlCommand shouldn't the sql statement be SELECT TOP 1 EMP_ID ...

Comment: A _random_ selection allows repeats. You'll need to explain in more detail what you want, e.g. keep removing values at random from a virtual hat.

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, it appears you are using [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb), so you should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [EMP_ID]
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE [Attendance] = 'Present'
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

By using [`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql), each row will be given an GUID and then the table will be sorted accordingly.

`NEWID()` creates a unique value of type uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Yes correct, i'musing SQL Server Express LocalDB. I've try with your sql query but it is not working also.Are my code correct after the sql query?

Comment: What error do you get (if any)? Set a breakpoint on line: `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)` and see if there are any rows returned from your query. Also, try the query using [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) and see what you get.

Comment: I didn't get any error..just the label only display 'Nan'.

Comment: I don't know how to using SSMS.

Comment: @Ash93 Ok, that is another issue. The answer targets the question you have asked. Now you have a new issue, which involves NaN (Not A Number), which needs more research and possibly a new question post with that new problem. I'm not suggesting you edit this post, but rather spend some time researching your issue, debugging, and then if you're stuck, then asking a new question on this site.

Comment: @Ash93 SSMS is a really excellent (free) tool that will help you test your queries you've got in your application. Once installed you can connect to your database and test your SQL query and work with the database objects.

Comment: I think the reason it shows NaN because my employee ID is a number with letter. Example 'INT1234'.So are that the reasons why i cannot select data from database?